# GPO Printer Share - Terminal Server is added printer multiple times

Tags: group-policy, terminal-server, network-printer, windows-server-2022

I have created a GPO for some of our users to roll out the printer (the same printer with different settings):

[image]
[image]

The printer is also assigned to the user accordingly, as you can see here on the TS:

[image]

However, in the printer settings, the printer appears multiple times:

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening.
I have also manually deleted the printers, logged the user on and off again, the problem still persists.
Anyone has a tip for me?

Comment: Did you solve this by chance?